# I cant get the content of a listbox to update after i edit its itemssource (which is a DB)

Tags: c#, database, wpf, linq, listbox

I have a listbox in a wpf application that gets its displayed data from a .mdf local DB in the background. I have a form that adds new data to the listbox but i cant get the listbox to update/refresh to also show the newly added data.

My code:

```
private void Add_Mitarbeiter_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tb_Mitarbeiter_Nachname.Text == "" && tb_Mitarbeiter_Vorname.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Leer");
            } else
            {
                Mitarbeiter ma = new Mitarbeiter
                {
                    Vorname = tb_Mitarbeiter_Vorname.Text,
                    Nachname = tb_Mitarbeiter_Nachname.Text,
                    Belastung = 0
                };

                dataContext.Mitarbeiter.InsertOnSubmit(ma);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }

            UpdateMitarbeiterList();
        }

public void UpdateMitarbeiterList()
        {
            lb_Mitarbeiter.ItemsSource = null;
            lb_Mitarbeiter.ItemsSource = dataContext.Mitarbeiter;
            lb_Mitarbeiter.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        }
```

And my .xaml:

```
<ListBox x:Name="lb_Mitarbeiter"
                                 Height="250"
                                 Margin="2"
                                 BorderThickness="1"
                                 Style="{StaticResource VirtualisedMetroListBox}" 
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lbMitarbeiterTemplate}"
                            />

<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="lbMitarbeiterTemplate">
            <StackPanel FlowDirection="LeftToRight"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Vorname}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text=" "></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Nachname}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
```

Setting the ItemsSource of my listbox to null and then adding the ItemsSource again doesnt work.

Quick update:
I fiddled around a little bit and noticed something weird. I also call the UpdateMitarbeiterList(); method in the applications _OnLoad method. If i dont call it there but only after i added a new item to the database it shows both items in the listbox. So it seems its not correctly reapplying the ItemsSource even though im setting it to null and add it again.

Edit: Added the whole code with the definition of the database.

```
public partial class MainWindow : MetroWindow
    {
        LinqToSqlDataClassesDataContext dataContext;

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ThemeManager.ChangeAppStyle(Application.Current, ThemeManager.GetAccent("Red"), ThemeManager.GetAppTheme("BaseLight"));
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SCVT_Aufgabenplaner.Properties.Settings.SCVT_Aufgabenplaner_DBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            dataContext = new LinqToSqlDataClassesDataContext(connectionString);
        }

        private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateMitarbeiterList();
        }

        public void UpdateMitarbeiterList()
        {
            lb_Mitarbeiter.ItemsSource = null;
            lb_Mitarbeiter.ItemsSource = dataContext.Mitarbeiter;
            lb_Mitarbeiter.SelectedValuePath = "Id";
        }

        #region Button Click Methoden
        private void Add_Mitarbeiter_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (tb_Mitarbeiter_Nachname.Text == "" && tb_Mitarbeiter_Vorname.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Leer");
            } else
            {
                Mitarbeiter ma = new Mitarbeiter
                {
                    Vorname = tb_Mitarbeiter_Vorname.Text,
                    Nachname = tb_Mitarbeiter_Nachname.Text,
                    Belastung = 0
                };

                dataContext.Mitarbeiter.InsertOnSubmit(ma);
                dataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }

            UpdateMitarbeiterList();
        }

        private void del_Mitarbeiter_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(lb_Mitarbeiter.SelectedValue.ToString());
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Databasedefinition:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Mitarbeiter] (
    [Id]        INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Vorname]   VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Nachname]  VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    [Belastung] INT          NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Did you debug your code to check if `dataContext.Mitarbeiter` contains the added element after SubmitChanges?

Comment: I always checked by viewing the database afterwards and it did contain the added element. I verified it by debuging my code just now.

Comment: You should consider using the MVVM style of coding for WPF rather than code behind. Many tutorials are available on the web.

Comment: Shouldn't it be possible to do such things without MVVM though? I thought MVVM is more suitable for large and complex applications

Comment: What you are showing here should just work. Without further information we won't be able to answer your question. It is however bad design to set ItemsSource to null and then reassign it, because that would usualy recreate all items in the ListBox. Consider assigning an ObservableCollection to the ItemsSource only once, then add and remove elements to/from that collection.

Comment: I have added the whole code to the original post with the definition of the database aswell. I will have a look on how to add the collection from my database to an ObversableCollection now

Comment: Okay i managed to use a ObservableCollection and everything is working fine now. Thank you very much!